# import.io Connector - with Javascript

Tags: import.io

I'm trying to extract the email from this [page] (http://royalenfield.com/locateus/genuine-parts-distributors/) by choosing country, state, and city. I can't get Connector to cooperate. I enabled javascript. I went through all the steps to get the email, but it keep asking me to record the query, over and over again. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Connectors are quite hit and miss when it comes to sites like the one you are trying..

However there is a workaround for this particular site that you might want to try:

If you notice when the page has changed to display the email values the url is in the following format:
http://royalenfield.com/locateus/genuine-parts-distributors/?**country=90&state=4&city=119**

You could train an extractor to extract just from these types of pages, and then run all the URLs with different **country=X&state=Y&city=Z**

This would avoid the temperamental connector steps and having to enable javascript.

N.B if you look in the html of the website you can see the values for the 3 fields above.

This one is "state":

```
<select id="divState" class="styled width110 hasCustomSelect" style="-webkit-appearance: menulist-button; width: 214px; position: absolute; opacity: 0; height: 30px; font-size: 12px;">
<option value="-1">Select State</option>
<option value="2">Andhra Pradesh</option>
<option value="4">Assam</option>
<option value="5">Bihar</option>
<option value="6">Chandigarh</option>
<option value="7">Chhattisgarh</option>
<option value="10">Delhi</option>
<option value="11">Goa</option>
<option value="12">Gujarat</option>
<option value="13">Haryana</option>
<option value="15">Jammu and Kashmir</option>
<option value="16">Jharkhand</option>
<option value="17">Karnataka</option>
<option value="18">Kerala</option>
<option value="20">Madhya Pradesh</option>
<option value="21">Maharashtra</option>
<option value="27">Orissa</option>
<option value="29">Punjab</option>
<option value="30">Rajasthan</option>
<option value="32">Tamil Nadu</option>
<option value="501">Telangana</option>
<option value="34">Uttar Pradesh</option>
<option value="36">Uttarakhand</option>
<option value="37">West Bengal</option>
</select>
```